# Extending Visual Studio Propertygrid with a single Assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

Is it possible to "extend" the visual studio property grid so that new properties 
will show up after add a dependency (assembly) ? Or is this only possible using addons.

For example a new property under "build action".

Hopefully its clear what i want to do.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`Implementing and Using Automation Extenders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y92k2w2.aspx) to get started. [`EnvDTE.IExtenderProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.iextenderprovider.aspx) is what you want. I don't have any experience with implementing it though.